# Word Frequency Graph plot using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, import, frequency, word-frequency

I have a large text file with around 10 million unique words and their frequency in two columns like following:

```
apple 10
banana 21
pineapple 7
orange 9
...
```

I want to plot a graph, with frequency in Y-axis and word in X-axis. I have used the 'load' command but it doesn't seem to work. I get the following error:

```
Error using ==> load
Unknown text on line number 1 of ASCII file C:\Users\..\Desktop\inputdata.txt
"aa"
```

Any solution for how I can plot the graph?

Answer (score 1):

try [`importdata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html), for example:

```
 a=importdata('inputdata.txt')
```

`a.data` - will output the numeric values vector, `[10,21,...]`

`a.textdata`  - will output a cell array with the words,  `apple`, `banana`, etc

So if you want to sort according to frequency:

```
[b idx]=sort(a.data,'descend')
plot(a.data(idx));
```

another option is to use `barh`, like this:

```
[b idx]=sort(a.data)
barh(a.data(idx));
set(gca,'yticklabel',a.textdata(idx))
```

[image]

However, this would only be suitable for a limited list of words, not 10 million...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot load a `.txt` file. You need to use file I/O functions, such as `textscan`.

```
fid = fopen('inputdata.txt');
data = textscan(fid, '%s%f')
fclose(fid);
```

`data` will be a 1x2 cell. The contents will be:

```
<4x1 cell>  [10;21;7;9]
```

`data{1,1}`, which is the 4x1 cell will be:

```
'apple'
'banana'
'pineapple'
'orange'
```

You can access the strings like this:

```
data{1,1}(2)
```

will output `'banana'`.

And access the numbers like this:

```
data{1,2}(2)
```

will give you 21, which is the corresponding number for banana.